# Applying data annotation on entity framework auto generated file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I have generated entity framework designer classes . After Generating the designer what is the most nicest and cleanest way to apply data annotation to the properties there . I have 3 classes there

Comment: This post shows how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915957/using-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-with-entity-framework-4-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Open up the EF designer, click on whatever you want to give documentation to, and fill in the "*Documentation*" field in the properties tab.</strike>

Ah, you are talking about attributes, not annotations.  See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050714/adding-custom-property-attributes-in-entity-framework-code).

**In short - you can't do it.**  If you absolutely need attributes, you'll have to write your own Entity classes (POCO), which is only supported in the new version of Entity Framework (in .Net 4.0)

Comment: Well can I write this in documentation  [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter The GroupName")]? If not then where can i write these

Comment: I am entering this [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter The GroupName")] in the docomentation but it is coming in the file with the comments tag  //