# entity framework 4.1 code generation, problems with generated code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, razor, entity-framework-4.1

When I update my Entity model my code generated classes (ie. Model.tt) are rebuild, this is expected.
But lets say I want to have this

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
```

above some datetime property.

My id is to have a class to inhered the base class via

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public override DateTime? Day
    {
        get { return base.Day; }
        set{ base.Day = value; }
    }
}
```

Maybe there is another way to do this, but can I make the code generated class have all (or some) properties virtual ?

cheers
sushiBite

Comment: I'd start with looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050714/adding-custom-property-attributes-in-entity-framework-code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using the **override** keyword I use the **new** instead, and thus don't need to have the property virtual