# How to prevent entity framework from updating classes in the context.cs file?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to Entity Framework, so I appologize if this is not a valid question.

I started using .NET Web Api a couble weeks ago and when I have to deal with more complex entities I run into problem with json serialization. After some research, I found different approaches, for example:

Global.asax.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling= Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

OR

For each property (in the context.designer.cs file) that I don't want to serialize, add:

```
[JsonIgnore]
```

The first didn't work for me, so I went with the [JsonIgnore] attribute.

Unfortunately, every once in a while I have to make changes to the Entity Framework context design and as soon as I save those changes, I lose the attributes that I had added to properties that I don't want to serialize.

Question then is: Is there a way to set JsonIgnore permanently to specific properties? Or a way to prevent Entity Framework from overriding changes on a specific property or class?

Or even... Is JsonIgnore the best approach?

Thanks

EDITED:

Serialization StackTrace:

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Self referencing loop detected with type 'Pathfinders.Data.Natural_Person'. Path '[0].Natural_Persons[0].Gender.Natural_Persons'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","StackTrace":" at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_c()\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)"}}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050714/adding-custom-property-attributes-in-entity-framework-code

Comment: could you share what error are you seeing when serializing?

Comment: Error: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Comment: that error message is not really helpful:)...could you share the entire stack trace?

Comment: check this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongyes/archive/2012/09/04/loop-reference-handling-in-serializer.aspx