# C# Partial auto generated class cannot add attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I have a partial class which is auto generated. I wish to add some attributes to the auto generated properties. I have read through and followed the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).aspx. However it does not work.

Please see below an example of one of the auto generated properties in the partial class Order.

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.Int64 TradeID
{
    get
    {
        return _TradeID;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_TradeID != value)
        {
            OnTradeIDChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("TradeID");
            _TradeID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("TradeID");
            OnTradeIDChanged();
        }
    }
}
private global::System.Int64 _TradeID;
partial void OnTradeIDChanging(global::System.Int64 value);
partial void OnTradeIDChanged();
```

My partial class is shown below. In the xml message that is create the tag is named after my property "TradeID" and not "iId" as specified in XmlElement attribute. I cannot see why though?

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Order.OrderMetadata))]
public partial class Order
{
 internal sealed class OrderMetadata
    {
        // metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated
        private OrderMetadata() { }

        [XmlElement("iId")]
        public Int64 TradeID;
     }
 }
```

Comment: The additional attributes will not appear in reflection queries, whatever component is consuming the attributes has to know about the metadata type and look there for the additional attributes. AFAIK the XML serializer doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure that the new `Order` class you added is in the same namespace as the auto-generated one?  If they are in different namespaces, it won't work since they will be totally separate classes.

Comment: If the XML serializer doesn't know about the metadata type how do I go about making sure it does know about the metdata? Both partial classes are in the same namespace as well.

Comment: You need to find a way to tell whatever is auto-generating the code to put a value for the `Name` property of the `DataMemberAttribute` in the auto-generated code.  What is generating the code -Linq to SQL? Linq to Entities? Something else?

Comment: The entity framework is auto generating the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding custom property attributes in Entity Framework code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050714/adding-custom-property-attributes-in-entity-framework-code)